# Maximum Operating Depth of a Jaeger

Tags: pacific-rim, jaeger

My sister was watching Pacific Rim the other day so as a fan of the movie I decided to join her.  I've never really cared about the science of the movie because I've always taken it at face value.  It wants to be about robots fighting monsters and it delivers.  Good enough for me.  This time however I came up with a somewhat more in depth (pun intended I suppose) question that I couldn't find a definitive answer for.

That question is: What is the maximum operational depth of a jaeger, or, how deep underwater can a jaeger be and still function properly?

At the end of the movie two jaegers submerge themselves in the ocean and travel all the way to the breach.

The Pacific Rim wiki states that the breach is located in the challenger deep.
http://pacificrim.wikia.com/wiki/Breach

Wikipedia suggests that the challenger deep is well, really deep.  Up to 35,814 feet deep.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenger_Deep

This seems incredibly deep for a giant robot to work against the water pressure and not get crushed.  In light of this I was wondering if anyone had found any canonical info or had any solid theories about the maximum operating depth of a jaeger.

Thanks as always,

Alex

Comment: Well, the crush depth for a Jaeger is clearly more than 35,000 feet.

Comment: May I humbly suggest that you never watch [this movie](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298814/)

Comment: Ha!  I've heard things about The Core, I know to never watch it seriously.

Comment: I don't recall this being mentioned in the novelization. I'll check the art book tonight. It's got some tech specs that weren't mentioned elsewhere.

Comment: @phantom42 - I've had a look through "[Pacific Rim: Man, Machines, and Monsters](http://www.amazon.com/Pacific-Rim-Man-Machines-Monsters/dp/1608871827)". I couldn't see anything useful.

Comment: @Richard is correct. More generally, Pacific Rim [ignores](http://movieline.com/2013/01/09/pacific-rim-vs-real-world-physics-giant-robots-guillermo-del-toro/) what's physically plausible in favour of cool fights between aliens and giant robots. Crush depth is the least of the concerns for a jaeger engineer, better just to sit back and enjoy the ride. :-)

Comment: If the answer is that there is no definitive answer that's fine with me.  I love that the movie doesn't bog itself down with facts and scientific explanations.  I was just kind of hoping that there would be some astronomical number listed as a jaegers crush depth, because that'd be fun.

Comment: Especially with how they were working on the air pressure changes of the Jaegers moving down city streets affecting the windows of those buildings, I doubt they overlooked this aspect of physics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>As much as I hate to post a negative, the simple fact is that they appear to have **no officially confirmed crush depth.**</s>

<s>I've read through every source I can think off; the movie script, the screenplay, the official novelisation, the "making of" book and the various interviews given by the staff and crew. Short of an out-of-the-blue word-of-god answer from the Writer or Director, the best conclusion I can draw is that **the Jaegers were proofed to work in depths up to (and including) 36,000 feet, as evidence by them actually doing so in the film.**</s>

<s>Beyond that, we only have assumption and guesswork.</s>

Having procured a better copy of the [official tie-in novelisation](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17162161-pacific-rim), I can confirm that the maximum operating depth of a normal Class I and Class II Jaeger is approximately 13,000 to 21,000 feet, a depth described as "*[abyssal](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abyssal)*". Several Jaegers (notably Gypsy Danger and Cherno Alpha) are evidently capable of operating a greater depths, below the 21,000 feet mark and presumably up to and including the 36,000 feet needed to penetrate the Pacific Breach. This is why they were pre-selected for Operation Pifall:

> Cherno Alpha's Conn-Pod is torso-mounted to accommodate cranial
>   expansion for incendiary fuel supply and energy storage. Designed for
>   long-range patrols in the hostile environments of Russia's Bering and
>   Arctic coastlines. Suggest Cherno Alpha be designated mission
>   alternate to carry nuclear payload in Operation Pitfall, as its
>   physical durability at abyssal depths will exceed other available
>   Jaegers.